# Adobe Air for Android with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am creating a android application using Adobe Flash CC, the database connection is working perfectly when I run it in desktop. I can locate the .db file and use SQLite browser to view the tables in my database. Now my problem is when I publish it and install it in my android phone(not rooted) and use adb shell from android sdk to locate the .db file, I can't seem to locate the default path of the database in data/data/packagename/dbname.
Here's my code in opening the DB.

```
    function openDatabase():void
    {
    var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("TrialAndError.db");
    connection = new SQLConnection();
    connection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onOpen);
    connection.openAsync(dbFile, SQLMode.CREATE);
    }
```

In adb shell I am trying to pull the .db file

```
adb pull data/data/air.flash.android.trialanderror/databases/TrialAndError.db D:
```

but I get the result

```
remote object 'data/data/air.flash.android.trialanderror/databases/TrialAndError.db' does not exist
```

I tried different method like run-as packagename but it didn't work as well. Am I in the right path? Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect path perhaps? You are storing you file at the root, but trying to access databases/TrialAndError.db. That could be the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your second is false. The applicationStorageDirectory is accessible from anywhere by anyone.

Comment: Hmm. Is that true for phones that are not rooted as well?

Comment: By definition yes. That is the purpose of applicationStorageDirectory. Where that folder is located depends on platform, system, os, etc  so its location is not guaranty but its public access is.

Comment: Ok. I stand corrected then. Thank you for pointing that out. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the native path of your file. This is easily done:

```
trace(dbFile.nativePath);
trace(dbFile.url);
```

Note that that path will always be the same on one given device but can completely change on another device.

Comment: by doing trace(dbFile.nativePath); and trace(dbFile.url) i get this result

Comment: app-storage:/TrialAndError.db where can i find it? I'm sorry for my noob question. Can't locate it in adb shell

Comment: how can I know that the .db file is stored in my android device?